# PHP numeric array order

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, numeric, implode

I have an array and want to create a new numeric array. This looks like this:

```
$created_old = explode("_", $result[$i]["created"]);
$created_new = array();
$created_new[0] = $created_old[2];
$created_new[1] = $created_old[0];
$created_new[2] = $created_old[1];
$created_new[3] = "";
$created_new[4] = rtrim(explode(":", $created_old[3])[2], ")");

//Get name from the database

$created_new[3] = $name;

$created = implode("_", $created_new);
```

This version works just fine, but the previous was missing one line, so the code would be this:

```
$created_old = explode("_", $result[$i]["created"]);
$created_new = array();
$created_new[0] = $created_old[2];
$created_new[1] = $created_old[0];
$created_new[2] = $created_old[1];
//$created_new[3] = ""; - I am missing
$created_new[4] = rtrim(explode(":", $created_old[3])[2], ")");

//Get name from the database

$created_new[3] = $name;

$created = implode("_", $created_new);
```

In the second code the string `$created` is in the wrong order. The index 4 and 3 are switched. If it would be an associative array I would understand this but as it is an numeric array I assume the indices to increase numerically and beeing ordered like this. As I have a working version I do not need help to fix this code but rather understand why the code behaves as it does...

Best regards
JRsz

Comment: There is not any `numeric` array in php. All are associative.

Comment: It is not relevant for my question, therefore I did not post it: FYI ist is a string I read from the database which has a format like this: `123_123_123_abc:(abc:123)`

Comment: `$created_new = array_fill(0, 5, '');` initialization should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All PHP arrays are associative. There's no such thing as a "numeric array" expect in colloquial speech. A key can be either a string or a number, it doesn't matter. Keys are still ordered by their order of insertion and never implicitly ordered by their value. You would not be surprised by this behaviour I assume:

```
$arr['a'] = 1;
$arr['c'] = 3;
$arr['b'] = 2;
// ['a' => 1, 'c' => 3, 'b' => 2]
```

The exact same mechanics are at work in your "numeric array".

If you want to sort your keys, you need to do so explicitly using [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort).

Comment: True. You can use `print_r($created_new)` check the array content.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to live with it. Though this is a bit odd I will bear it in mind for future work. Thank you :)

Comment: @JRsz Other languages have separate *numerically indexed lists* and *key-value maps*; PHP conflates both of them into one type of *associative ordered key-value maps*.

Comment: You don't have to live with it. You can use `ksort` to *explicitly* order your keys in the order you're expecting

Comment: That is true, but If I create it in a way I need it to be then I do not have this overhead. So in the sense of perfomance one only has to keep this in mind :D

Comment: `ksort` is a sorting(nlogn). `array_fill` initialization can be better. Anyway, even in other languages you should to initialize your array.