# PHP alter array with array_search and array_column

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array (`$myArray`) which I want to alter:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "fancyLink"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "200"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "fanyLink2"
  }
}
```

I have two POST arrays which have the following structure.
First array `$number`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "100"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "200"
}
```

and the second array `$links`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "newFancyLink"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "newFancyLink2"
}
```

To alter the `$myArray` in order to replace one or more links according to the `$number`-value I wanted to use the following line

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    $myArray[array_search($number[$i], array_column($myArray, "0"))][1] = $links[$i];
}
```

But this does not work, it sets both links of `100` and `200` to the same value (the second link)

I wrote this code which works, but I would like to use the other line instead or at least compare the perfomance of it

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++)
    {
        if($myArray[$j][0] == $number[$i])
        {
            $myArray[$j][1] = $links[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `$number`-value as a key would make this a lot easier but this is not an option for me.

**EDIT after Solving**

In case anybody wants to know, both versions are alost identical fast. 10000 runs each result in this runtime:

```
0.10158801078796
0.10160994529724
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `array_column($myArray, "0")` should be `array_column($myArray, 0)` instead (since it is not an associative array)? That way it seems to work for me.

From the [PHP-manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php)

```
array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
```

> column_key
>
> The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an associative array or property name. It may also be NULL to return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with index_key to reindex the array).

Comment: Hm, Because PHP has only associative arrays and numeric arrays pretend only to be numeric I thought it would not matter, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854038/php-numeric-array-order
But thank you, I will look into it

Comment: I checked, your answer works. PHP is strange sometimes, at least to me :D
I accepted your answer as it solved my particular problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_map` and `array_walk` functions:

```
$numLinks = array_map(null, $number, $links);
// you may also iterate via a regular 'foreach' loop
array_walk($myArray, function(&$v, $k) use($numLinks){
    if ($v[0] == $numLinks[$k][0]) $v[1] = $numLinks[$k][1];
});

print_r($myArray);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => newFancyLink
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => newFancyLink2
        )
)
```

Comment: Hm, this may work but I already have some working code and am simply curios why my first try is not working because as far as I understood it it should...

Comment: *this may work* - It works fine. As for your code, the second argument for the `array_column` function - *this value may be an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an associative array or property name*. But you have specified an integer key as a string

Comment: Hm, Because PHP has only associative arrays and numeric arrays pretend only to be numeric I thought it would not matter, see this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/37854038/php-numeric-array-order But thank you, I will look into it :) PHP is strange sometimes...